Make explode modifer only appear if weight paint above threshold
(Update)
I seemed to have figured it out kinda, I've used an attribute node to drive the geometry alpha for the damage and destroyed geometry so the original nice mesh isn't touched but the destroyed appears over the top. The scaling isn't perfect as the destroyed meshes need to be slightly larger than the original and I can't figure out how to do that uniformly. But this is the result. I had to do this to each shader on each of the destroy and destroyed meshes.


Original Question:
I'm trying to make a space ship damage effect, using explode modifier with particleSystem and a cloth sim using an empty to control weight paint which drives where the damage is to happen. It works well, but the explode modifier is always visible and since it's slicing up the mesh it looks all weird.

Is it possible to have the geometry of the explode modifier only be visible when it's weight paint is above a certain threshold (since it's controlled by an empty)? So it only appears where the damage is happening, not over the entire geometry?
Or is there a way to make the explode modifier look not weird until pieces have moved?

